# calculate particle size distribution from AFM measurements

Tags: python, c++, matlab, image-processing, particles

I am trying to obtain a radius and diameter distribution from some AFM (Atomic force microscopy) measurements. So far I am trying out Gwyddion, ImageJ and different workflows in Matlab.

At the moment the best results I have found is to use Gwyddion and to take the Phase image, high pass filter it and then try an edge detection with 'Laplacian of Gaussian'. The result is shown in figure 3. However this image is still too noisy and doesnt really capture the edges of all the particles. (some are merged together others do not have a clear perimeter).

In the end I need an image which segments each of the spherical particles which I can use for blob detection/analysis to obtain size/radius information.

Can anyone recommend a different method?

[[image: AFM height image]

[image: AFM Phase Image]

[image: Phase, Difference, Laplacian]

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try a [Granulometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granulometry_(morphology)), it was designed for something really similar. There is [a good explanation of granulometry here starting page 158](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ibv/reader/chapter6.pdf).

The granulometry will perform consecutive / increasing openings that will erase the different patterns according to their dimensions. The bigger the pattern, the latter it will be erased. It will give you a curve that represent the pattern dimension distributions in your image, so exactly what you want.

However, it will not give you any information about the position inside the image. If you want to have a rough modeling of the blobs present in your image, you can take a look to the Ultimate Opening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Avizo, it's a powerful software for dealing with image issues, especially for three D data (CT)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).